# How can Window from Object Library in Interface builder be used

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uiwindow

I've been doing iOS developement for a while but never used or seen someone using the Window object. I tried googling about it but I did not found any relevant articles. I know about 'UIWindow' object and how it can be used from code. So what can be done with the Window object from Interface Builder? When and why whould I choose to use it?

Comment: Please check this apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/

Comment: I does not say anything about interface builder.

Comment: Currently storyboard are using in interface builder.but before iOS 5.0 storyboards are not available.nib's used for App UI.Window object in interface builder is automatically crated by Xcode templates.another usage of window object is to create custom alerts, notifications, keyboard etc.

Comment: I know that, I am interested more in how can it be used from interface builder. Something like creating the notifications or alerts from interface builder. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

So Far, interface builder is not support you custom a UIWindow's subclass.